# Space spanned by orthogonal vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

If there are $M$ non-zero orthogonal vectors $X_1$,$X_2$,.....$X_M$. The dimension of the vector space spanned by these $M$ vectors is?

Answer given is $M$ but I am not able to understand how is it $M$.

Comment: So what is your definition of dimension? Largest linear independent set?

Comment: I meant dimension of vector space. I have edited the question.

Comment: I understand. There are at least two possible definitions (which are equivalent). Can you write the definition you are familiar with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that those vectors were linearly dependent. Then you can write at least one of them as a linear combination of the others. Without loss of generality suppose that $$x_m = a_1x_1 + \dots + a_{m-1}x_{m-1}$$

and that not all the $a_i$'s are zero.

Since the vectors are orthogonal, $\langle x_i , x_m \rangle = 0$ for all $i = 1, \dots, m-1$. Then using the linearity of the inner product,

\begin{align*} 0 &= \langle x_i, x_m \rangle\\ &= a_1 \langle x_i, x_1 \rangle + \dots a_{m-1} \langle x_i, x_{m-1} \rangle \\
&= a_i \langle x_i , x_i \rangle.
\end{align*}

for all $i = 1, \dots, m-1$.But $x_i \neq 0$, so $\langle x_i , x_i \rangle \neq 0$. Therefore $a_i = 0$ for all $i = 1, \dots , m-1$. This is a contradiction, hence the vectors must be linearly independent. Since we have $m$ linearly independent vectors, they span a space of dimension $m$.

Comment: At the end how did you get ai<xi,xi> . That is the only part I didn't understand.

Comment: My one more doubt is :- As all the vectors are linearly independent, why can't we have more vectors than M in vector space ? Linear combination of these vectors can produce more vectors right?

Comment: @Zephyr Addressing your first question: $\langle x_i , x_j \rangle = 0$ if $i \neq j$.

Comment: For your second question, there $\textbf{are}$ more than $m$ vectors in the vector space generated by them. Dimension is not the number of vectors in the vector space, dimension is the largest number of linearly independent vectors in the space.

Answer (score 1):

Orthogonal vectors are necessarily **independent** vectors.  The span of n **independent** vectors has those n vectors as basis.  Since the space has n vectors as a basis it has dimension n.